# process.start from ASP page, where to put exe file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Just a quick question, where do I put the exe that I am trying to launch in an ASP project? It cant see it in the bin folder.

Comment: you might need to sanity check that the relevant user (identity of the asp.net app pool, most likely) has the ability to read and execute the file.

Comment: Can you clarify you are wanting to shell a exe on the server? why do it with an ASP.Net site and not using server OS tools, like set the exe to open on startup? I can understand wanting to do it on the client-side, but why on earth on a server? From experience TS'ing peoples servers who've done this, it is a recipe for disaster...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a full path to `Process.Start`:

```
Process.Start(Server.MapPath("~/bin/whatever.exe"));
```

However, `~/bin/` is meant for .Net assemblies; it's generally better to put external EXEs in `~/App_Data/`.

Note that you can only execute programs on the server, not the client.

Comment: strictly speaking, you don't have to give a full path to the exe all the time - if it's in your PATH, then it'll still work fine.  From a PowerShell prompt, for instance, you can start a new cmd with: [diagnostics.process]::start('cmd.exe')

Answer (score 1):

Remember that your Website is running on a server so if you Shell anything (Process.Start in an ASP.Net application) it will be opened on the Server - not the Client PC.

Be sure you test this in production and when you do shell processes on a server (which I would not advise) dont forget to close them, otherwise you will end up with strange errors on the server.

Comment: Your first sentence is false. Although the second one is true, it's possible that it's what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid security concerns and multiple process running in parallel. from asp page i would rather prefer to queue up the request for process start in some table than have other process like windows service in background to pick it up from queue and execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath), "PathToExeFromWWWRoot");
```

Comment: That is an odd way to arrive at the path, and it's still likely to break depending on what `pathToExe` is.

Comment: Apparrently, not... I meant the contents of the string. Like, if it is just a filename. Or if it is a rooted path.

Comment: Good idea editing your original, offensive comment. I've removed my DV since you edited to make the second parameter of `Combine` more clear. Note that another reason for the DV was that you provided no explanation with your code; an explanation would have made my comments moot. Other than that, I'm done here :)