# How to Run exe File To Client From Server in Asp.net Webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have exe file in root of Asp.net Application and

I Want to run exe file in client machine.
how can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [process.start from ASP page, where to put exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544854/process-start-from-asp-page-where-to-put-exe-file)

Comment: Not sure this is possible. How can you run exe file for examlpe on Mac or Linux client machine.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security risk you can't do it that way. Think yourself, how would you like if it would be possible that you enter a website with a javascript, which runs exe and deletes all files on your c drive.

Maybe a possible solution for you would be giving your customers a link to download an exe. and ask them to run it themselves